# move command not working in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I tried to move everything except a few items to a folder using a bash script with the following content. I tried these commands in the terminal first and got the expected results, but putting them inside a script produces the error mentioned below.

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*.log | *.img) $1/build_files/ 2> /dev/null
```

**ERROR:**

```
build.sh: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
build.sh: line 36: `    mv !(*.log|*.img) $1/build_files/ 2> /dev/null'
```

It'll be very helpful if someone could solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a space in the shebang

Comment: Such space in the shebang is allowed. I would prefer to remove it, but this is not the problem.

Comment: This is not the script that generates the error! The shown script has only 3 lines, but the error message is abut line 36. You must agree we are not seers, at least most of us are not :) Use the tool `shellcheck` to verify your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find to do that:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! \( -name '*.img' -o -name '*.log' \) -exec mv {} $1/build_files/ \;
```

The argument `-type f` makes find look only for regular files. You have to remove it if you want to match any kind of file.

The argument `-maxdepth 1` make find look for targets only on the current directory (by default the starting point of the search is the current directory).

See the [find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more options and the different file types that you can target.

Comment: Thanks @TitouanT ! Your solution works for files but it does not move any folders in the directory! I would like to move all the folders as well.

Comment: remove the `-type f` then.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround to this, as I've implemented:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv * build_files/ 2> /dev/null
mv build_files/*.log ./ && mv build_files/*.imx ./ && mv build_files/*.sh ./
```

I know this involves multiple iterations, which are not necessary and I'm open for improvements.